# glmmLasso function won't finish running

Tags: r, statistics, ram, glm, mixed-models

I am trying to build a Mixed Model Lasso model using glmmLasso in RStudio. However, I am looking for some assistance.

I have the equation of my model as follows:

```
glmmModel <- glmmLasso(outcome ~ year + married ,list(ID=~1), lambda = 100, family=gaussian(link="identity"), data=data1,control = list(print.iter=TRUE))
```

where outcome is a continuous variable, year is the year the data was collected, and married is a binary indicator (1/0) of whether or not the subject is married. I eventually would like to include more covariates in my model, but for the purpose of successfully first getting this to run, right now I am just attempting to run a model with these two covariates. My data1 dataframe is 48000 observations and 57 variables.

When I click run, however, the model runs for many hours (48+) without stopping. The only feedback I am getting is "ITERATION 1," "ITERATION 2," etc... Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Please note, I am running on a machine with only 8 GB RAM, but I don't think this should be the issue, right? My dataset (48000 observations) isn't particularly large (at least I don't think so). Any advice or thoughts would be appreciated on how I can fix this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to be a comment, but I feel like you deserve an answer to this confusion.

It is not uncommon to experience "slow" performance. In fact in many glmm implementations it is more common than not. The fact is that Generalized Linear Mixed Effect models are very **hard** to estimate. For purely gaussian models (no penalizer) a series of proofs gives us the REML estimator, which can be estimated very efficiently, but for generalized models this is not the case. As such note that the Random Effect model matrix can become ***absolutely massive***. Remember that for every random effect, you obtain a block-diagonal matrix so even for small sized data, you might have a model matrix with 2000+ columns, that needs to go through optimization through PIRLS (inversions and so on).

Some packages (glmmTMB, lme4 and to some extend nlme) have very efficient implementations that abuse the block-diagonality of the random effect matrix and high-performance C/C++ libraries to perform optimized sparse-matrix calculations, while the [glmmLasso (link to source)](https://github.com/cran/glmmLasso/blob/master/R/glmmLasso_RE.R#L488) package uses R-base to perform all of it's computations. No matter how we go about it, the fact that it does **not** abuse sparse computations and implements it's code in R, causes it to be **slow**.

As a side-note, my thesis project had about 24000~ observations, with 3 random effect variables (and some odd 20 fixed effects). The fitting process of this dataset could take anywhere between 15 minutes to 3 hours, depending on the complexity, and was primarily decided by the random effect structure.

So the answer from here:

Yes glmmLasso will be slow. It may take hours, days or even weeks depending on your dataset. I would suggest using a stratified (or/and clustered) subsample across independent groups, fit the model using a smaller dataset (3000 - 4000 maybe?), to obtain initial starting points, and "hope" that these are close to the real values. Be patient. If you think neural networks are complex, welcome to the world of generalized mixed effect models.